# PHP Bcrypt Salt as of 7.0

Tags: java, php, bcrypt

I am working on an application in which I have to compare 2 hashed passwords in a database, one password is being generated in PHP with `$Password = password_hash($RawPassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);`
While the other password that is being sent to the database to compare with the PHP hashed password is generated in Java with `String hashedPassword = BCrypt.hashpw(password);`
As of PHP 7.0 the salting is automatically generated, how can i know what salt is being applied in PHP so i can apply it to my java code? Or is there a way to still specify the salt that is no longer in the documentation for PHP Hashing?

Comment: The salt is part of the outputted hash, so you can easily extract it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt#Description

Comment: I'm a bit confused about *why* this is a problem. What actual flow are your users going through that you need to care about which salt was used when a password was hashed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard idea behind the vast majority of bcrypt impls is that the thing that is in the database looks like `$2y$10$AB` where A is 22 characters and B is 31 characters for a grand total of 60. A is: `left(base64(salt + 00 + 00), 22)` and B is: `left(base64(bcryptraw(salt + pass)), 31)`. (`2y` refers to the hash algorithm/ EDIT: 2y and 2a are more or less interchangible; most bcrypt impls treat them the same, and it is unlikely to matter which one is there. The `10` refers to the # of bcrypt rounds applied. 10 is common and usually what you want).

where:

- `base64(X)` = apply base64 conversion, using . and / as the 63rd and 64th char.
- `+` is concatenate, i.e. `salt` (a 16-byte byte array) gets 2 zero bytes added.
- `left(chars, size)` means: Take the first `size` chars and discard the rest.
- `salt` is the salt in bytes and `pass` is the password, converted to bytes via UTF_8. (if not converting via UTF-8, it's generally $2a$ instead, and you should upgrade, folks with non-ascii chars in their password get pretty bad hashes in the older $2a$ mode!

This one string contains **everything** that a bcrypt impl needs to check if a given password is correct or not. Thus, all non-idiotic bcrypt library impls have just two methods and no others:

```
// This is for when the user creates an account or edits their password.
// send the password to this method, then take the string it returns,
// and store this in your database.
hash = crypto.hashPass(password);

// This is for when the user tries to log in. For 'hash', send the thing
// that the hashPass method made for you.
boolean passwordIsCorrect = crypto.checkPass(password, hash);
```

EDIT: NB: A truly well designed crypto library calls these methods `processNewPassword` and `checkExistingPassword` to avoid the kind of confusion that caused you to ask this question, but unfortunately, nobody out there seems to have had the wherewithal to think for 5 seconds about what their names suggest. Unfortunate. Security is hard.

if your BCrypt API doesn't work like this, get rid of it, and find a standard implementation that works like this.

It sounds like you're **using the wrong method**. To check passwords, don't use hashPass. Use checkPass, or whatever goes for checkPass in your impl (it might be called `checkPw` or `verifyPw` or `validate`, etcetera. It take 2 strings).

Thus, **you should never generate a salt, nor ever extract a salt from such a string**. Let the bcrypt lib do it. Those 'hashes' that standard bcrypt libraries generate (the `$2y$` string) are interchangible; your PHP library can make em and your java library can check em, and vice versa.

If you MUST extract the salt (but don't):

- take those 22 characters, after the `$protocol$rounds$` part.
- append 'aa' to this.
- base64decode the result.
- this gets you 18 bytes. toss the last 2 bytes, which contain garbage.
- The remaining 16 bytes are the salt.

You should absolutely not write this - your bcrypt library will do this.